# How to write 5E9 in Excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a program and storing "5E9" in to excel and its storing as exponent value in excel.

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")= "5E9"
```

Output showing like this 5.00E+09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `NumberFormat` to `Text`

```
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value2 = "5E9"
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to "escape" the string so Excel reads it literally, using `'` at the start:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")= "'5E9"
```

Comment: I would like to write the string through VBA.

Comment: @Developer_World - That is VBA?